# How do I add text to multiple filenames using Python?

Tags: python, addition, file-rename

I have a series of files that I need to add the creation year (2007) to the end of the filename:

Currently:
NewZealand_cities.shp
NewZealand_roads.shp
etc.

Need:
NewZealand_cities2007.shp
NewZealand_roads2007.shp

I have been able to remove segments of text but cannot add for some reason.  Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: os.rename not working for you?  ...maybe show us what you have

Comment: Can you show us what you've come up with thus far?  It's hard to point you in the right direction, when we don't know what you have tried.

Comment: Please provide more information. What do you mean that you haven't been able to add text to the filenames? Are you using the move/rename function in the OS module?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this:

```
import os
name, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)
os.rename(fname, name + '2007' + ext)
```