# Python, rename files in directory

Tags: python, openpyxl, pathlib

I have a folder of xlsx files that I want to edit (add columns...) and save with a new name. This code here works but saves in a new directory with same name. How can I modify the second last line of the code to give it an extension to the original name (i.e. originalname_addtext.xlsx)

```
from pathlib import Path
from openpyxl import load_workbook

cwd = Path(os.getcwd())
source = cwd / Path('/Users/lidia/Desktop/xlsx/')
dest = cwd / Path('/Users/lidia/Desktop/output/')
for filename in source.glob('*.xlsx'):

.....


wb.save(dest / filename.name) 
wb.close()
```

Comment: so, your question is to "How to add a custom text to file name before saving, in Python"?like below?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487758/how-to-add-an-id-to-filename-before-extension


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915698/how-do-i-add-text-to-multiple-filenames-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
wb.save(dest / filename.name)
```

You want this:

```
wb.save(dest / f'{filename.stem}_addtext{filename.suffix}')
```

`filename.stem` gets you the `.name` without the suffix (i.e. '.xlsx')